# Click event target gives element or its child, not parent element

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2

I've got this HTML element:

```
<div class="list-group">
    <a href="javascript:;" @click="showDetails(notification, $event)" class="list-group-item" v-for="notification in notifications" :key="notification.id">
        <h4 class="list-group-item-heading" v-text="notification.title" />
        <p class="list-group-item-text" v-text="notification.created_at|moment" />
    </a>
</div>
```

And this Javascript:

```
return new Vue({
    methods: {
        showDetails: function (notification, event) {
          this.notification = notification

          console.info(event.target)
        }
    }
}
```

The problem is that `event.target` return the exact element I click. That means it can be the `a` element, or one of its children (`h4` or `p`).

How do I get the `a` element (the element with the `@click` handler), even if the user clicks on one of its children?

Comment: have you tried to pass `this` to your function `showDetails`? like `showDetails(notification, $event, this)`, your third argument should be your anchor now

Comment: Have you tried using `this` instead of `event.target`?

Comment: No, `this` will return the Window instance itself.

Answer (score 189, accepted):

use `event.currentTarget` which points to the element that you attached the listener. It does not change as the event bubbles

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/currentTarget

Comment: Note that you only get the object not the event as if it was for that element for this. So e.g. offsetX and offsetY is still relative to the child element and not the one that you actually attached the event listener for (yes its very confusing).

Answer (score 24):

Alternative solution with CSS:

```
a * {
    pointer-events: none;
}
```

> The element is never the target of pointer events; however, pointer
>   events may target its descendant elements if those descendants have
>   pointer-events set to some other value. In these circumstances,
>   pointer events will trigger event listeners on this parent element as
>   appropriate on their way to/from the descendant during the event
>   capture/bubble phases.

Ref: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/pointer-events#Values